# Using Google Chart's timeofday data type is drawing the hour data incorrectly. All hours are displayed 5 hours behind

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to draw a simple bar chart using the Google Charts API but I am very confused as to what I'm doing wrong with the 'timeofday' column data type. The Google Charts documentation says that timeofday should be an array of 3 or 4 numbers and they site this as an example

"For example, the time 8:30am would be: [8, 30, 0, 0], with the 4th value being optional ([8, 30, 0] would output the same timeofday value)."

When I open their example in a JSFiddle, the time you see above in my quoted example gets displayed in the bar chart as "3:30:45" This is very perplexing. All of the data I enter for time is displayed as 5 hours behind the hour value I enter. The hour value in the example above is 8, but when drawn becomes a 3.

Here is function where the data is entered

```
function drawChart() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('timeofday', 'Time of Day');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Emails Received');

      data.addRows([
        [[7, 30, 0], 5],
         [[9, 30, 0], 12],
          [[20, 30, 0], 3],
           [[22, 30, 0], 22]
      ]);

      var options = google.charts.Bar.convertOptions({
        title: 'Total Emails Received Throughout the Day',
        height: 450
      });

      var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

it must be a bug with *Material* charts

if you `console.log` the formatted values prior to drawing
-- or --
draw a `corechart` in addition

this causes the values in the **tooltip** to show correctly on the *Material* chart

but nothing seems to resolve the **axis values**
tried adding `hAxis.format` and `hAxis.ticks` -- neither worked

the *CoreChart* seems to work fine
you could use `theme: 'material'` to get it close to the look of a *Material* chart

see following example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('timeofday', 'Time of Day');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Emails Received');

    data.addRows([
      [[7, 30, 0], 5],
      [[9, 30, 0], 12],
      [[20, 30, 0], 3],
      [[22, 30, 0], 22]
    ]);

    console.log(data.getFormattedValue(0, 0), (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset());
    console.log(data.getFormattedValue(1, 0), (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset());
    console.log(data.getFormattedValue(2, 0), (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset());
    console.log(data.getFormattedValue(3, 0), (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset());

    var options = {
      title: 'Total Emails Received Throughout the Day',
      height: 450,
      hAxis: {
        format: 'H:mm',
        ticks: [data.getValue(0, 0), data.getValue(1, 0), data.getValue(2, 0), data.getValue(3, 0)]
      },
      theme: 'material'
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));

    var chart2 = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));
    chart2.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages:['bar', 'corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<div id="chart_div2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your addRows call. The horizontal axis doesn't align no matter the dataset.  However, you can update your ***var options*** to resolve this. Below example formats the hAxis from 8a.m. to 2p.m skipping every other hour. The key is to tick on timeofday data.  For more information refer to Google doc:  https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart and scroll to down to the ***hAxis.ticks*** section.

```
hAxis: { 
  title: 'Time of day',
      ticks: [[8,0,0],[10,0,0],[12,0,0],[14,0,0]]
}
```